# Get community link in email template

Tags: community, email-template, vf-email-template

In the Visualforce page context, we have the `$Site.Prefix` formula available to get the community's path prefix so we can adapt our link for the internal users.

I'm wondering if something similar can be achieved on Visualforce Email Templates. For example, if I have a community user that should get an automated email with a link for a record. The link must be `company.force.com/community/<record_id>` instead of `company.my.salesforce.com/<record_id>` for internal users. Is it possible to dynamically detect the users's community?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar use case with a partner community. After extensive search, I couldn't find a proper solution, so we used the following workaround.

We used a Custom Label to store the Community URL and then reference it in the Visualforce Template like this:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Label.Partner_Community_URL  & '/' & relatedTo.Id}" >{!relatedTo.Name}</apex:outputLink><br/>
```

So save the value of `https://company.force.com/community` in a Custom Label you create.
 You could add a `rendered` attribute to the outputLink element based on the value of `relatedTo.ContactId`, which will be filled for external users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The link part seems pretty straightforward, but how can I distinguish an internal from an external user, since the user records are on the same table (and have the same prefix)?

Comment: Figured out that the simplest way of doing so is to create a "default community" field on the user object and get it there. If the field is blank, then there's no community.

Comment: Yea, or as I already wrote in my answer, you can look at the ContactId field. Community users are always linked to a contact, thus that field will have a value. Internal users will not have a value there.

Comment: Now I get it. That's even better. :)